# Am I able to make certain parts of a texture glow with post process bloom?

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, 3d, blender

So I have these mushroom models, and some of the faces are blue as opposed to purple. 
I was hoping to make the top part of the mushroom glow, but not the stem of the mushroom. Currently i just use a point light in Unity but it doesn't look very good.
Any help would be awesome! Thank you

[Glowing Mushrooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJyLp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can try making the textures emissive by adding an emission map, that way they will glow when using post processing bloom.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't know about emission maps! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The bloom post-processing effect relies on a material or light's intensity values. So, you'd need a separate material for the stem and another for the head. For the head of the mushroom, you then need to set the material's emission colour as well as the albedo. This will allow you to make it glow slightly and then the bloom will then spread out that glow for you.

As per Bean5's post, you can assign an emissions map if you don't want to use two separate materials. That way, if you have one mesh then only parts of your model will glow.